# Testing if elements are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hidden

Ok guys so I am testing if elements are hidden, problem is if the parent element is hidden then the children are considered hidden as well so the line that I append is being appending even if the children elements that aren't technically "display:none"

```
function checkIfVisible() {
  var checkLeft= $('#left').children('.module').filter(':hidden');
  if(checkLeft.length > 0) {
   if(!$('.resetLeft').length) {
      left.prepend('<span class="resetLeft">Reset Left Widgets</span>');
    } 
  }
```

I run this script on page load, and when ever any of the children elements are clicked to be hidden. How do I stop the script from assigning the prepended element from being added if the parent elements is hidden but none of the children are hidden (Display:none) in style?

So basically.

If `#left` is hidden (parent) and none of the children are I don't want the `resetLeft` to be prepended. But if `#left` is hidden and 1 or more of the children of it are display:none then prepended. even if left isn't hidden I need to this work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took what Blender sort of said to do but I changed it around to work just the way I wanted. I used the `&&` and logical operator...

```
function checkIfVisible() {
 var checkLeft=  
    $('#left').is(':visible')
    &&
    $('#left').children('.module').filter(':hidden').length > 0;
   if(checkLeft) {
       if(!$('.resetLeft').length) {
      left.prepend('<span class="resetLeft">Reset Left Widgets</span>');
     }
   }
```

This worked wonderfully for me, and all I did was add the function to the click function of showing the `#left` element!

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
var visible = $('#left').is(':hidden') && $('#left').children('.module').filter(function() {
    return this.style.display === 'none';
}).length === 0;
```

But this seems like a hack. Why are you forced to do this?

Comment: Can you please tell why did you use `===`. '==' is also working perfectly.

Comment: @PankajGarg: Why should I use `==` instead? `===` is the right equality operator 99% of the time.

Comment: `style.display` return string which is `==` to `none`

Comment: @PankajGarg: It's best to use strict equality unless you have a reason not to use it.

Comment: Understood your point. `1==="1"    // false, because they are of a different type`

Comment: @PankajGarg: Exactly. With loose equality, `0 == ''`, but that isn't true with strict equality.

Comment: A strict operator never does type coercion so you are doing an exact comparison which a double equals operator returns the type coercion. Anyways I will try this out... This didn't work, as when I make some of the children hidden the element does not get prepended. I have to try some other wyas